# Can you link multiple tablixes on a key field in a single SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report in SSRS to show evaluation scores. It has three sections, and I need to link them all together on the PreceptorID field (2108 in this case). The top two sections are from the same query. I am filtering the results in each one to separate the counts because they have different column names. The third section is a subreport showing comments from evaluators. It also has the PreceptorID field in the data but is not displaying it. It has two parameters that should be populated by the main report query, but that does not appear to be happening. The report is returning all comments instead of only the ones with the matching PreceptorID.

This first image is from Crystal Reports showing how the finished product should look. 
[image]

This is what I am getting from SSRS. It is showing counts for multiple people at the top. The counts in the middle are actually correct. They are all for the one person. The next person's counts are on the next page. The comments at the bottom are also not filtering on the one PreceptorID. 
[image]

This image showing the subreport parameter that should be linking it back to the main query. 
[image]

How can I tell all three sections to only return data for the same person on one page, and another person on the next page?

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing more but what happens if you run the subreport on it's own and pass in the parameters manually? If this does not show the results you expect, then it likely a problem with the subreport's dataset query.

Comment: I added the PreceptorID parameter to the WHERE clause and can enter which one I want at runtime. It looks correct when I do this. The only problem I have now is that I need to see all people, 1 per page.

Comment: Do you mean you want the first two sections for 1 person, then the sub report for one person, then repeat for the next person?

Comment: All three sections for the same person. The next person on the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would redesign the report structure slightly. This is only my personal preference, there are several ways to achieve this but I find this way easier to manage and maintain.

You'll need two subreports and a master report.

You already have the 2nd subreport so no extra work required there.

I would take you current report, strip out the link to the current subreport and change it so it only processes a single person (just like your existing sub report).

So SubReport1 will have the two tables from your current main report only. It will only accept a single person as a parameter (or pair of parameters in your case)

SubReport2 will be your current subreport. Again it only accepts a single person.

Next create a new report. This will be the master report.

Add a dataset that contains just enough info for list of people you want to report over. So the dataset query might be as simple as

```
SELECT PreceptorID, ClerkshipID FROM myTable ORDER BY PreceptorID
```

Add a table to this report and set it's dataset property to the dataset you just created.

Change the default (details) row group to group and order by whatever makes each record unique (maybe both the two columns listed above, may only one will be required, only you will know this).

Right-Click on the row header to the left of your table and do "Insert Row => Inside Group Below".

Remove all but one column

You should now have a table with 2 rows per group.

Right click the top cell in the group and do "Insert => Subreport", go to the subreport properties and point this to SubReport1 (or whatever you called it) and set the parameters has you have done previously.

Repeat this for second row, this time pointing to your second subreport.

In the row group properties, set page breaks to "Between each instance"

That should be it. This was done from memory so might not be 100% but based on the info in your question you should be able to work it out from here.

**Things to check if this is not working**

- Open each subreport and test it by passing in parameters manually. Each subreport should only be returning data for a single person.
- The master report should have a dataset that returns each person once i.e. if there are 10 people in total this dataset should only contain 10 rows.
- The table in the master report should contain only two rows
- Both rows must be EITHER within the same row group, or, if you have no other row groups, they will both be in the detail row group.

The report design should look something like this if you have a row group by person
[image]

or like this if you only have detail rows.

[image]

- Finally, make sure the parameters you pass to your subreports are the **Field** values from your master report's dataset, NOT your master reports parameters.

Comment: I'll add some things to check to the answer later.